# Excel horizontal bar chart cannot format axis as dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am using Excel 365 MSO 64-bit. I am creating a horizontal bar chart. I right-click the x-axis and go to Format Axis --> Axis Options. There should be an "Axis Options" category, but it is missing. As it is now, I can only display the x-axis in day units (as it is formatted by number, not date).

I know that I can go to Format Axis --> Axis Options --> Number --> (Category) Date, and that will make the x-axis display in date format instead of numbers. However, that does not fix the problem that I can only display the x-axis categories in terms of days. If I choose the "Major Units" to be 365, for example, I will get barlines at 1/1/2016, 12/31/2016, 12/31/2017, 12/31/2018, 12/31/2019, 12/30/2020 when what I want is 1/1/2016, 1/1/2017, 1/1/2018, 1/1/2019, etc. Likewise, if I want major gridlines to be every quarter, the best I can do is choose 90 units and I get 1/1/2016, 3/31/2016, 6/29/2016, 9/27/2016, when what I want is 1/1/2016, 4/1/2016, 7/1/2016, and 10/1/2016. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried changing the min and max bounds of the axis?

Comment: Yes, that changes the start and stop dates, but it doesn't change the intervals.

Comment: What are you calling the X axis? In a horizontal bar chart, the X axis is the vertical axis, by default on the left side of the chart.

Comment: Are you trying to make a Gantt chart? Go here: [Gantt Charts in Microsoft Excel](https://peltiertech.com/excel-gantt-charts/).